# "Page not Found" ? Content well and alive, Saved, Published, and some. Can't figure it out

Tags: content-management

I'm getting a "Page not Found" for a content item that should display as all its siblings in the same category. But this one is recalcitrant.

We've opened in Content Editor, did a small edit, Save, Published and still nothing..

I'm currently searching in /Sitecore interface for a diagnostic page. Maybe it's a content indexing failure? Or a 'Security' flag somewhere inadvertently checked/unchecked, or kept to the default of not showing?

Also I've been comparing this no-show item with a showing one in database (Items table <=> Versionedfield table) without finding anything significant.

Thank you for any advice.

Comment: Try switching to `web` database and checking if that item is there. Check that item `read` access rights. Check if item has publishing restrictions

Comment: I feel like we might need more context... screenshots, error messages, etc.

Comment: Please also check the publish restriction of the item: https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/content_authoring/publishing/preview_and_setup/set_up_publishing_restrictions_for_an_item

Comment: I think you should explain in more details if item is bucket item, served by routes or by index look up or it is just straight up page item. if any other items with the same template is getting displayed or not? Also check if it is in cm database and not in cd database etc.

Comment: All thank you, scrutinizing further we noticed that this content item had been imported differently than others of the same vein in a bulk upload, due to a metadata difference. We'll be able to either modify, either remove/recreate manually.

With your insights I'm better prepared for possible causes of such "Page not Found" cases.